# Sed is not replacing the string after running iconv

Tags: sql-server, bash, sed, terminal

I have a SQL Server dump that I received from a client and I'm trying to convert to a mysql insert. The file is very large, some 100gb file. I was thinking that I might run the following commands to get it converted over to mysql compatible dump file.

```
sed -i 's/\[/\`/g' file.sql
sed -i 's/\]/\`/g' file.sql
sed -i 's/\r/;/g' file.sql
```

Everything up to this point worked fine and I even split the file and ran it through an import test to see if it would work and it did.

Now my only problem is that the large 100gb file has this at the start:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT `table` ON ;
```

and I can't just open it and edit it. So I need to do it through the command line.

I ran into a problem where there was a special character at the start of the file so I ran the following and it did remove it:

[image]

```
iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-8 -c file.sql
```

I am down to the last thing which is replacing the `SET INDENTITY_INSERT` line with a commented out line:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT `table` ON ;

--- SET IDENTITY_INSERT `table` ON ;
```

For some reason I can't get it to replace SET with -- SET. Here's everything I've tried:

```
sed -i 's/SET/--SET/g' file.sql
sed -i 's/SET/-- SET/g' file.sql
sed -i 's/SET IDENTITY_INSERT/--SET IDENTITY_INSERT/' file.sql
```

I think I may be having a weird file format issue. I've been at this for way too many hours PLEASE HELP!

Comment: I have one string at the very start and very end of the file. Let me give that a try!

Comment: Also, just figured out the file is in binary format and not plain/text. Small progress.. might be getting close to a solution.

Comment: That which does not kill us, only makes us stronger (-;! But surprized there is no "export as text" feature you could use.  Good luck.

Comment: for removing the first line (and incidentally the BOM that comes with it) you could just do a `sed -i 1d file.sql`